# What reasoner to use with AllegroGraph RDF Triple Store?

Tags: rdf, owl, triplestore, allegrograph, topbraid-composer

I created an Ontology in TopBraid Composer and loaded it to AllegroGraph Triple Store. RDFS++ Inferencing (explained in example 19 [here](https://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/6.1.6/java-tutorial/jena-tutorial.html#RDFS++%20Inference)) works.

Now I want to use a Semantic Reasoner that can do more than just RDFS++ Inferencing (e.g. Pellet, HermiT or FACT..).

Which one would you recommend?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the actual target is to search in the AllegroGraph Triple Store for inconsistencies between metalevel ontology and instances assigned to it. Which reasoner can be used with Allegrograph ?